# Run Simulink model parallel

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, simulink

I would like to run a complex Simulink model in a parfor loop on many cores with different data.
However, I didn't have success yet so I created a simple model and tried to run it parallel with the same data.

The model looks like this, adding two signals:
[image]
With the code:

```
function Result  = Add (X, Y)
Result = X + Y;
```

The script to run the model is the following:

```
if matlabpool('size') == 0
    matlabpool('open',4);
end

parfor i = 1:4
    data=ones(1,20);
    X=timeseries(data);
    Y=timeseries(data);
    output = sim('model_test','StopTime','5');
    Result = output.get('Res');
end
```

However, the following error occurs:
[image]

I don't understand why the variables are not existing. I know that paralell computing is always critical in terms of variable access, but I didn't have success with simulink parallel running yet. Can you please explain the error to me and how to solve it?
Thank you very much!

**Answer to am304**: Thank you, the answer helped me in the way that I now know how to change constants with set_param in the parfor loop and I understand why it doesn't work for timeseries.
However for timeseries I am still struggling.
I tried several versions, also this one:

```
if matlabpool('size') == 0
matlabpool('open',4);
end

data=ones(1,20);
X=timeseries(data);
Ybase=timeseries(data);

parfor i = 1:4
    Y = evalin('base', 'Ybase');
    output = sim('model_test','StopTime','5');
    Result{i} = output.get('Res');
end
```

The variable Ybase exists in the workspace, but the following error occurs:

[image]

As you see, the variable Ybase exists in the base workspace. Do you know how to use evalin or assignin to access properly?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's because your data `data` only exists in the workspace of the main MATLAB, not in any of the instances fired up by `matlabpool` on the workers. Have a look at [Workspace Access Issues](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/running-parallel-simulations.html#br93zto) in the documentation for more details on how to resolve this, with some examples illustrating the two approaches:

> The MATLAB workers, however, do not have access to the workspace of
>   the MATLAB client session where the model and its associated workspace
>   variables have been loaded. Hence, if you load a model and define its
>   associated workspace variables outside of and before a parfor loop,
>   then neither is the model loaded, nor are the workspace variables
>   defined in the MATLAB worker sessions where the parfor iterations are
>   executed. This is typically the case when you define model parameters
>   or external inputs in the base workspace of the client session. These
>   scenarios constitute workspace access issues.

[...]

> **Resolving Workspace Access Issues**
>
> When a Simulink model is loaded into memory in a MATLAB client session, it is only visible and
>   accessible in that MATLAB session; it is not accessible in the memory
>   of the MATLAB worker sessions. Similarly, the workspace variables
>   associated with a model that are defined in a MATLAB client session
>   (such as parameters and external inputs) are not automatically
>   available in the worker sessions. You must therefore ensure that the
>   model is loaded and that the workspace variables referenced in the
>   model are defined in the MATLAB worker session by using the following
>   two methods.
>
> - In the `parfor` loop, use the `sim` command to load the model and to set    parameters that change with each iteration. (Alternative:
>     load the    model and then use the g(s)et_param command(s) to set the
>     parameters    in the `parfor` loop)
> - In the `parfor` loop, use the MATLAB `evalin` and    `assignin` commands to assign data values to variables. Alternatively,    you can
>     simplify the management of workspace variables by defining    them in
>     the model workspace. These variables will then be    automatically
>     loaded when the model is loaded into the worker    sessions. There
>     are, however, limitations to this method. For    example, you cannot
>     have tunable parameters in a model workspace. For    a detailed
>     discussion on the model workspace, see [Model Workspaces](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-model-workspaces.html).

**EDIT**

Here's what I would do in your particular example:

```
if matlabpool('size') == 0
   matlabpool('open',4);
end

data=ones(1,20);
X=timeseries(data);
Y=timeseries(data);

parfor i = 1:4
    assignin('base','Y',Y);
    output = sim('model_test','StopTime','5');
    Result{i} = output.get('Res');
end
```

Another option is to include `X` and `Y` in the model workspace so that the model is self-contained.

Comment: Hi am304, thank you for the answer! I tried evalin and assignin but it didn't work out like I wanted. Can you please see the post above, I made an edit there as response. Thanks and Regards!